# Creating Hive Table In Databricks using Spark driver (datafile format = AVRO)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, databricks

TableQuery:

```sql
CREATE  TABLE `zdp`.`asdasdEntity_1` (`ter` string COMMENT 'system generated')  
 ROW FORMAT  SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
    STORED AS  
        INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
```

output:

1. table is created in databricks
2. cannot describe table properties using (desc extended tablename)      gives below output:

```
error_error_error_error_error_error_error
string
from deserializer
cannot_determine_schema
string
from deserializer
check
string
from deserializer
schema
string
from deserializer
url
string
from deserializer
and
string
from deserializer
literal
string
from deserializer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE avroExample
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='{ "namespace": "org.apache.hive",
    "name": "first_schema",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
            { "name":"string1", "type":"string" },
            { "name":"string2", "type":"string" }
        ] }');
```